# XPath Selector integer value not equals

Tags: xml, xpath

Friends,

I need to select the message if attribute `RequestID` value is **not equal** to `4`.
How can i achieve this.

My `xpath selector` configuration is as follows:

```
<int-xml:xpath-selector evaluation-result-type="boolean">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//ns2:RequestID">
        <map>
            <entry key="ns2" value="http://www.test.com/Schema/schema2" />
        </map>
    </int-xml:xpath-expression>
</int-xml:xpath-selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using the following expression:

```
expression="//ns2:RequestID[text() != '4']"
```